# Bootstrap alignment of label and regular text

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get the text to properly align vertically with no luck.  Could I get some assistance?

[image: Alignment Problem]

Here is the underlying code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Permalink</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            http://www.somedomain.com/cart/@Model.Offer.Id
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Offer.DateCreated, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Offer.DateCreated)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Offer.DateCreated)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static), you can use `<p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>` to properly align static text in form groups.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I put it in the containing divs! <div class="col-md-10 form-control-static"> Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to your `<div class="col-md-10">` in order for `vertical-align` to work.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Bx4/)

Comment: This didn't help.  I selected the answer above which worked perfectly.

Comment: The other example is working because `p` is inline element. Anyway, I agree with you that other example is better as you don't need additional styling with it.

Comment: Yes.  I didn't use the <p> tag though.  I put the class "form-control-static" into the existing <div> which made it work.  Plus, like you said, it is clean too.